# Centered Single Character in UILabel off by 1 pixel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am setting up the following UILabel:

```
    UIImageView *textImageBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top100bar"]];
    textImageBackground.frame = CGRectMake( 104.0f, 6.0f, 215.0f, 104.0f);

    [self.contentView addSubview:textImageBackground];

    _lblRank = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    self.lblRank.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.lblRank.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.lblRank.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:10];
    self.lblRank.frame = CGRectMake(153.0f, 45.0f, 41.0f, 41.0f);
    self.lblRank.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.09 green:.62 blue:.11 alpha:1.0];
    [textImageBackground addSubview:_lblRank];
```

If the text of _lblRank is set to a string 2 or more characters long, it centers the text perfectly, with an equal amount of pixels to the left and right of the text.  However, if the string only has a single character, the text favors the left by 1 or 2 pixels.  I measured this by grabbing a screenshot of the simulator and zooming and measuring in Preview.

I have attached screenshots of single and multi character versions.

Thanks so much!
Stephen

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to post the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

First size to fit the label:

```
[self.lblRank sizeToFit]
```

Then center it horizontally:

```
CGRect frame = self.lblRank.frame
frame.origin.x = self.lblRank.superview.frame.size.width/2.0 - frame.size.width/2.0;
self.lblRank.frame = frame
```

Make sure the label has a superview before you use the code above.

Comment: When I add this code, the label is now sized to fit the text, but the single character labels still have their text favoring the left side by 1 pixel.  Hopefully I'll be able to post screenshots soon to show this.